# Computing pair-wise time differences between matching records in a data table

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

I have a three-column table of data of the following form:

```
TIME        MPID    CPID
16:45:51    10051   77845
16:45:51    10051   77845
16:46:52    10051   77846
16:46:53    10051   77846
16:48:38    10051   77847
16:48:38    10051   77847
16:48:39    10051   77995
16:49:31    10051   77848
16:49:31    10051   77848
16:51:03    10051   77849
16:51:03    10051   77849
```

Here the TIME column consists of timestamps of the form HH:MM:SS. The MPID and CPID columns are identification numbers; what they mean is not important for my question. The MPID values also don't play a role, except for the fact that they're present in the data set and need to be propagated to the output.

What I want is to identify pairs of rows which have matching CPID values and compute the difference between their corresponding times. So, for example, there are two rows (the third and the fourth) in the above example with CPID 77846. The corresponding times are 16:46:52 and 16:46:53, so I want to compute the difference:

```
16:46:53 - 16:46:52 = 00:00:01
```

I would also like to output this result in the following format:

```
MPID 10051 CPID 77846 Total time difference: 01 seconds
```

If a given CPID does not occur exactly twice in the data set then I want to ignore it.

The desired output for the given example data should look like this:

```
MPID 10051 CPID 77845 Total time difference: 00 seconds
MPID 10051 CPID 77846 Total time difference: 01 seconds
MPID 10051 CPID 77847 Total time difference: 00 seconds
MPID 10051 CPID 77848 Total time difference: 00 seconds
MPID 10051 CPID 77849 Total time difference: 00 seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Assuming *input* is the file with the differences, use `uniq -D` to
   show all lines with duplicated *3rd* fields *only*, which also gets rid of the header.  Then use `date`
   with the `%s` format to convert the times to seconds, and subtract
   those.  The rest is standard *shell*:

   ```
   uniq -D -f 2 input | 
   while read a b c && read d e f ; do 
       g=$(( $(date -d $d +%s) - $(date -d $a +%s) ))
       printf "MPID %s CPID %s Total time difference: %02i seconds\n" $b $c $g
   done
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   MPID 10051 CPID 77845 Total time difference: 00 seconds
   MPID 10051 CPID 77846 Total time difference: 01 seconds
   MPID 10051 CPID 77847 Total time difference: 00 seconds
   MPID 10051 CPID 77848 Total time difference: 00 seconds
   MPID 10051 CPID 77849 Total time difference: 00 seconds
   ```
2. An earlier spec, (as per [OP comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403659/time-difference-between-two-lines-linux?noredirect=1#comment721615_403659)), required a little more
   code:

   ```
   uniq -D -f 2 input | 
   while read a b c && read d e f ; do 
       g=$(( $(date -d $d +%s) - $(date -d $a +%s) ))
       printf "For %s %s time difference: %02i:%02i:%02i\n" \
               $b $c $((g/360)) $(((g/60)%60)) $((g%60))
   done
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   For 10051 77845 time difference: 00:00:00
   For 10051 77846 time difference: 00:00:01
   For 10051 77847 time difference: 00:00:00
   For 10051 77848 time difference: 00:00:00
   For 10051 77849 time difference: 00:00:00
   ```

Comment: It'd be better if, instead of `printf` with shell arithmetic, there was a way to use `date +%T` to convert `$g` to a zero-based output.

Comment: i create a small file with time difference:
Time        MPID  CPID
16:49:31 10051  77848
16:49:36 10051   77848
16:51:03 10051  77849
16:51:06 10051   77849
17:00:44 10051  77850
17:00:49 10051   77850
17:02:22 10051  77851
17:02:29 10051   77851
17:11:48 10051  77852
17:11:51 10051   77852
17:13:28 10051  77853
17:13:31 10051   77853

run the given script with myfile.csv. No output on screen.
If a given CPID does not occur exactly twice in the data set then I want to ignore it

Comment: @VivekNigam, If there's no output, check that the formatting isn't uneven, since the *1st* version of the code above gets confused by bad formatting.  The *2nd* version of the answer above is less fragile that way, so try that.  **Important**: data files can't be in comments, as the formatting is *lost* -- try [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) or something like it, or re-edit the opening question to include any problematic data.

Comment: @VivekNigam, For example, here's [myfile.csv](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/927d0053a67ec502ee4bfc0d95a51d08).  Testing that with either version of the above code seems to work fine.

Comment: I want to calculate time difference in milli seconds, what changes need to be done in given script , please help.       Example:                              14:00:04.909 - 14:00:05:320  = 00:00:00.589
I would also like to output this result in the following format:
MPID 10051 CPID 77846 Total time difference: 589 mili seconds
If a given CPID does not occur exactly twice in the data set then I want to ignore it. The desired output for the given example data should look like this:
MPID 10051 CPID 77845 Total time difference: 1400 milli seconds

Comment: @VivekNigam, Please skim `man date`, the `date` util offers about every possible date-related format option.  Hint: look for *"nano"*.   Then try to tweak the code in this answer accordingly.  If that doesn't work out, ask another question, and put a link to it in a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough shell-script that does what you want:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# pairwise_pid_time_diff.sh

# Write the data to a temporary file, sorted first by pid and then by time
cat "${1}" | sed 's/\s\+/ /g' | sort -k3,3 -k1,1 -n > sorted_pids.csv

# Compute the pair-wise time differences
for pid in $(cat sorted_pids.csv | cut -d' ' -f3 | uniq); do
    if (( "$(grep "${pid}" sorted_pids.csv | wc -l)" == 2 )); then
        time1_string="$(cat sorted_pids.csv | grep "${pid}" | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f1)"
        time2_string="$(cat sorted_pids.csv | grep "${pid}" | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f1)"
        time1_seconds="$(date -u -d "${time1_string}" +"%s")"
        time2_seconds="$(date -u -d "${time2_string}" +"%s")"
        date -u -d "0 ${time2_seconds} sec - ${time1_seconds} sec" +"%H:%M:%S"
    fi
done

# Delete the temporary file
rm sorted_pids.csv
```

To test it out, let's write your example data to a file:

```bsh
cat <<HEREDOC > pids.csv
16:45:51 10051 77845
16:45:51 10051 77845
16:46:52 10051 77846
16:46:53 10051 77846
16:48:38 10051 77847
16:48:38 10051 77847
16:48:39 10051 77995
16:49:31 10051 77848
16:49:31 10051 77848
16:51:03 10051 77849
16:51:03 10051 77849
HEREDOC
```

And then run the script:

```bsh
bash pairwise_pid_time_diff.sh pids.csv
```

This gives us the following output:

```
00:00:00
00:00:01
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
```

---

Since you seem to be running into trouble running the script, here's another version for the purposes of debugging:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# pairwise_pid_time_diff_debug.sh

# Write the data to a temporary file, sorted first by pid and then by time
1>&2 echo "Writing sorted data to temporary file."
cat "${1}" | sed 's/\s\+/ /g' | sort -k3,3 -k1,1 -n > sorted_pids.csv

# Compute the pair-wise time differences
1>&2 echo "Entering main loop..."
for pid in $(cat sorted_pids.csv | cut -d' ' -f3 | uniq); do
    1>&2 echo "Looking at pid: ${pid}"

    if (( "$(grep "${pid}" sorted_pids.csv | wc -l)" == 2 )); then
        1>&2 echo "Found matching pair."

        time1_string="$(cat sorted_pids.csv | grep "${pid}" | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f1)"
        1>&2 echo "Time 1 string: ${time1_string}"

        time2_string="$(cat sorted_pids.csv | grep "${pid}" | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f1)"
        1>&2 echo "Time 2 string: ${time2_string}"

        time1_seconds="$(date -u -d "${time1_string}" +"%s")"
        1>&2 echo "Time 1 in seconds: ${time1_seconds}"

        time2_seconds="$(date -u -d "${time2_string}" +"%s")"
        1>&2 echo "Time 1 in seconds: ${time2_seconds}"

        time_difference="$(date -u -d "0 ${time2_seconds} sec - ${time1_seconds} sec" +"%H:%M:%S")"
        echo "${time_difference}"
    fi
done

# Delete the temporary file
rm sorted_pids.csv
1>&2 echo "Deleted temporary file."
```

When I run this script I get the following output:

```
bash pairwise_pid_time_diff_debug.sh pids.csv
Writing sorted data to temporary file.
Entering main loop...
Looking at pid: 77845
Found matching pair.
Time 1 string: 16:45:51
Time 2 string: 16:45:51
Time 1 in seconds: 1510332351
Time 1 in seconds: 1510332351
00:00:00
Looking at pid: 77846
Found matching pair.
Time 1 string: 16:46:52
Time 2 string: 16:46:53
Time 1 in seconds: 1510332412
Time 1 in seconds: 1510332413
00:00:01
Looking at pid: 77847
Found matching pair.
Time 1 string: 16:48:38
Time 2 string: 16:48:38
Time 1 in seconds: 1510332518
Time 1 in seconds: 1510332518
00:00:00
Looking at pid: 77995
Looking at pid: 77848
Found matching pair.
Time 1 string: 16:49:31
Time 2 string: 16:49:31
Time 1 in seconds: 1510332571
Time 1 in seconds: 1510332571
00:00:00
Looking at pid: 77849
Found matching pair.
Time 1 string: 16:51:03
Time 2 string: 16:51:03
Time 1 in seconds: 1510332663
Time 1 in seconds: 1510332663
00:00:00
Deleted temporary file.
```

---

Instead of running the script, let's manually step through the process. First, let's create our data file:

```bsh
cat <<HEREDOC > pids.csv
16:45:51 10051 77845
16:45:51 10051 77845
16:46:52 10051 77846
16:46:53 10051 77846
16:48:38 10051 77847
16:48:38 10051 77847
16:48:39 10051 77995
16:49:31 10051 77848
16:49:31 10051 77848
16:51:03 10051 77849
16:51:03 10051 77849
HEREDOC
```

Next, let's sort the data - first by PID, then by time:

```bsh
cat pids.csv | sed 's/\s\+/ /g' | sort -k3,3 -k1,1 -n > sorted_pids.csv
```

And let's check that the file was written correctly:

```bsh
cat sorted_pids.csv
```

We should get the following output:

```
16:45:51 10051 77845
16:45:51 10051 77845
16:46:52 10051 77846
16:46:53 10051 77846
16:48:38 10051 77847
16:48:38 10051 77847
16:49:31 10051 77848
16:49:31 10051 77848
16:51:03 10051 77849
16:51:03 10051 77849
16:48:39 10051 77995
```

Now let's get the uniq PIDs from the data:

```bsh
user@host:~$ cat sorted_pids.csv | cut -d' ' -f3 | uniq

77845
77846
77847
77848
77849
77995
```

Let's try to compute the time difference for the first PID: 77845.

First let's get the first time string for 77845:

```bsh
time1_string="$(cat sorted_pids.csv | grep 77845 | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f1)"
```

And let's check that we have the correct value:

```
user@host:~$ echo ${time1_string} 

16:45:51
```

Now let's convert that to seconds:

```bsh
time1_seconds="$(date -u -d "${time1_string}" +"%s")"
```

And check what value we get:

```bsh
user@host:~$ echo ${time1_seconds}

1510332351
```

Now let's do the same for the second time string:

```bsh
time2_string="$(cat sorted_pids.csv | grep 77845 | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f1)"
time2_seconds="$(date -u -d "${time2_string}" +"%s")"
```

```bsh
user@host:~$ echo "${time2_string}"

16:45:51

user@host:~$ echo "${time2_seconds}"

1510332351
```

Now we compute the difference in seconds and convert it to a time-signature:

```bsh
difference=$(date -u -d "0 ${time2_seconds} sec - ${time1_seconds} sec" +"%H:%M:%S")
```

And check the result:

```
00:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks alot  for response, i copy same script on my server, create input file as csv file then run the script:

# bash TEST.sh TEST1.csv   but no result on screen
.
seems i missed something.:-(

Comment: Look at my updated solution. Trying running the "debugging" version of the script and tell me what you get.

Comment: Thanks alot
bash SHI.sh JIT.csv
Writing sorted data to temporary file. stuck here waiting

Comment: It didn't enter the loop? Did the `sorted_pids.csv` file get created?

Comment: No its not created

Comment: What happens when you run the command manually (`cat pids.csv | sort -k3,1 -n`)?

Comment: i Run following command
cat JIT.csv | sort -k3,1 -n >> HHHH.txt

its stuck no output in HHHH.txt

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "stuck". What OS are you using? What version of sort are you using? What happens when you run it *without* redirecting the output?

Comment: i run normal command " sort -k3 JIT.csv >> LLLL.txt" its worked

[root@logserver home]# uname -a
Linux logserver 2.6.32-642.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Apr 13 00:51:26 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Can you please answer the questions I asked? What OS are you using? What version of sort are you using?

Comment: [root@logserver home]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago)

Comment: I updated the script. Can you try it again?

Comment: Now:
[root@logserver home]# bash FNL.sh JIT.csv >> JIT.txt
Writing sorted data to temporary file.
Entering main loop...
Deleted temporary file.
no output on screen & file.
----------------------------------------------

sort command working fine
[root@logserver home]# cat JIT.csv | sort -k3,3 -k1,1 -n > sorted_pids.csv

checked sort command working

Comment: Look at the update. I added several manual steps at the bottom. Can you work through those and see where it fails?

Comment: cat sorted_pids.csv | cut -d' ' -f3 | uniq : No output on screen

difference=$(date -u -d "0 ${time2_seconds} sec - ${time1_seconds} sec" +"%H:%M:%S") : Success
No output

Comment: @VivekNigam Ok, then let's keep peeling the command apart. First do `cat sorted_pids.csv`, then `cat sorted_pids.csv | cut -d' ' -f3`.

Comment: @VivekNigam Also, I think I see what I may have done wrong. I updated the script again.